Body part associations with letters
I was curious, since I meditate by first focusing on each of my body parts to help calm myself, if there is designated corresponding letters for each part. I figured this would further deepen my meditative state. I found briefly some short mentions online and in one or two excerpts but nothing I found extremely definitive. However I feel like I’ve come across it before.
Does anyone have any insight?

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Check out Sefer Yetzirah
